# Use Quicktime to covert an audio file from AAC to AC3 via CLI?

Tags: bash, command-line, shell, osx-snow-leopard, quicktime

Basically I want to use Quicktime to convert an audio file from AAC to AC3, I thought I might be able to use Quicktime?

But I can't seem to be able to find the CLI command for it.

Comment: What operating system are you using? Reading http://www.softimageblog.com/archives/103, it seems that Quicktime itself doesn't support CLI very well, but has limited support for scripting on MS Windows (via COM) and OS X via Object-c binding.

Comment: Yeah I found a blog about QT DOS scripting, but I'm using Snow Leopard (Mac OS). Looks like ill have to go with ffmpeg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a C SDK so you could compile it into your own CLI command, but that is probably overkill.

There's plenty of people out there who have scripting Quicktime using Applescript and Automator - you can get to Applescript from the CLI via osascript.

Now my understanding is that osascript & Applescript are simply a front end onto an underlying object scripting bridge - but I've no idea if there is a more direct way to access.

What I ended up doing when I had a similar requirement to batch convert files was using Automator to script the conversion flow, then linked to a Folder Action - resulting in a folder that would automatically convert the file when copied into the folder (from the CLI or GUI - it's a background daemon, not a Finder thing).

You can create quite a nice pipeline of work that way.

Comment: Thanks for the in depth answer. I always forget about Automator.